# ActiveX control not showing up properly

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, activex, activexobject

I have an activex control which I have written using C#. It is essentially a user control which is being compiled into a dll. When I debug the program with visual studio the forms and controls appear normal. When I embed the control in a webpage using HTML the control functions properly but it does not render correctly. The fonts and proportions are off. (It is not a problem with the width and height setting). Also, I am using the latest version of the .net framework and internet explorer.

Comment: Silly question, but is the problem rendering (in the browser) on the same machine as where you debugged in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably something to do with auto scaling. And inheriting `Font`. Try explicitly setting the `Font` value on your `UserControl`